# Why is 0 less than Number.MIN_VALUE in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, numbers, double

Using Node.js, I'm evaluating the expression:

```
0 < Number.MIN_VALUE
```

To my surprise, this returns `true`. Why is that? And: How can I get the smallest number available for which the comparison works as expected?

Comment: `Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER`

Comment: @Vohuman: but isn't zero greater than all negative numbers?

Comment: `Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER` is `undefined` in Node.js 0.10.x.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`Number.MIN_VALUE` is `5e-324`, i.e. the smallest positive number that can be represented within float precision, i.e. that's as close as you can get to zero. It defines the best resolution floats give you.

Now the overall smallest value is `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` although that's not really numeric in the strict sense.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the behavior *and* pointing out a viable alternative :-)

Comment: I can't believe I actually had to look this up to find out why my code was wrong. I swear, javascript, sometimes...

Comment: I would say `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` is the *least* value (in the sense that no other values can be lesser), but not the *smallest*. The word "small" implies a small quantity, i.e. a value closer to 0, and "large" implies a value farther away from zero (-1000 is "larger" than 10). So in that sense, `-Infinity` is quite large, even if it is negative.

Answer (score 6):

`Number.MIN_VALUE` is equivalent to  5e-324 , which is greater than 0.

Comment: This is true. I think what's throwing people off is the negative exponent `-324`. I taught high schoolers who thought that `3 ** -2 === -9`.

Answer (score 2):

Since `Number.MIN_VALUE = 5e-324 = 5 x 10^-324` and it's **greater** than `0`(a little bit greater).
Read more [`here`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/number_min_value.htm).

Comment: `Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER` is `undefined` in Node.js 0.10.x.

Comment: Yes, sometimes people forget `e` notation. A positive number raised to a negative exponent is still positive. I taught high schoolers who thought that `3 ** -2 === -9`.

Answer (score 1):

```
`Number.MIN_VALUE` is equal to 5e-324 or 5*(10^-324);
```

it's math.
any positive number is greater than zero.

Answer (score -1):

Use `-Number.MAX_VALUE` instead of Number.MIN_VALUE to compare:

`0 > -Number.MAX_VALUE` returns `true`.

Comment: `-Number.MAX_VALUE` is not equal to `Number.MIN_VALUE`. Furthermore, `-Number.MAX_VALUE` is a negative number, so you're saying `0 > [a negative number]`, which is always true.